# Insert image to crystal reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Insert image to crystal report
I have ADO.NET data connection where i'm using

```
<xs:element name="Drawing" type="xs:byte" minOccurs="0" />
```

for image field, so how can i use that image byte data to display image in my crystal reports 2013.
I'm not using any backend coding because there's possible many images in that retrieved data,
Here's my data structure of table "Drawing" is image field of data which i have stored as byte
[image]

i'm using image contained report as sub report

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understood your question, but let me share something that may lead you to something useful. I understand you said there is no "backending code", but i hope this may contain some useful tip for your case.

When we use an image in Crystal Reports, it's type is base64Binary in the XSD.

In the dataset, it's type is byte[].

We save the image as a serialized string in the database. Something like that:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader binreader = new BinaryReader(stream);
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) stream.Length];
buffer = binreader.ReadBytes((int) stream.Length);
string serialized = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
```

We get it back as a byte array to put in the dataset:

```
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(serialized)
```

In the Crystal Report design tool, we just drag the field to the document.