# How to display images in Crystal Report that are retrieved as blob's from mysql?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

Currently we are saving images in our database as blob's they have been resized to be much smaller to not take up all to much space. We need to display a image on the Crystal Report Viewer (Crystal Report Viewer 13) and I retrieve this from the MYSQL database and convert it to a byte[] and my dataset has a column System.Byte[], but the Crystal Report Viewer still shows nothing. I haven't found a solution yet.

I've tried using OLE objects but with no success, and tried linking a picture to the dataset column but no success.

The results I keep getting is blank fields. Also tried to see if it shows up when I export it to PDF but shows up blank there as well. The result should be the image that is stored in the database

This is how i retrieve the blob from the MYSQL database

```
clsDataAccess getData = new clsDataAccess(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PAW.Data"].ConnectionString);
                getData.SQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from userimages where UserName = ?";
                getData.SQLCommand.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = UserName;
                System.Data.DataTable tblData = getData.PopulateDataTableWithParameters();
                if (tblData.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in tblData.Rows)
                    {
                        userImage.Name = item["Name"].ToString();
                        userImage.ContentType = item["Content"].ToString();
                        object LogoTest = item["Data"];
                        userImage.Data = (byte[])item["Data"];
                    }
                }
```

When I inspect the image I get this in the console
 http://localhost:31720/Areas/Administration/ReportsASPX/CrystalImageHandler.aspx?dynamicimage=cr_tmp_image_14fda631-5f94-4fa2-8419-f95f447fe08b.png

Comment: The link points to localhost. What is userImage? Can you use a dataset as the data source in your report?

Comment: @heringer userImage is the image the user saved as there profile picture, and the picture is saved a blob data in the database, the requirement was to show that image in the crystal report, but to not upload it to a folder But now the image gets saved to a folder before displaying the image in the report and the image path is sent to the url

Comment: This is how i deal with it, try to adapt to your case: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227513/insert-image-to-crystal-reports/23243126#23243126), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162526/how-to-view-dynamic-images-in-crystal-report-9-during-runtime-without-using-data/27192825#27192825)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way of access blob storage from inside mysql. I do however has a possible work around.

Why not store an id for the image in the database. Ensure the blob container has read public access. Inside of the report you could then have a link like "https://myblob.blob.azure.net/container/{id}", then just replace the {id} with the id retrieved from the database?

Comment: i have update the question on how i retrieve the blob from the MYSQL database